# "parentheses" vs "parenthesis"

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between "parentheses" and "parenthesis"?

Comment: As the answers point out, the one ending in -is is the singular, and the one ending in -es is the plural. They're pronounced differently, too. The singular in **-is** is pronounced /pə'rɛnθəsəs/, and the plural in **-es** is pronounced /pə'rɛnθəsiz/; the last syllable is identical to _sieze_ or _seas_. The difference in pronunciation is how we really tell; the spelling is Greek and doesn't represent English well at all. And, as you demonstrate, it's easy to confuse.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Parenthesis** is of course Greek and means in fact "insertion". It has taken the meaning of the signs " ( " or " ) ".

**Parentheses** is the regular plural.

Usually, you use a pair of the signs showing an insertion, then "between parentheses" - or brackets ; however, "in parenthesis" means : as an afterthought.

Answer (score 10):

If you're still confused after the different emphases given by Mark and Barrie,

**1** A **parenthesis** is

- **one** of the marks usually called (ordinary, or curved) brackets in the UK

**or**

- material set off by a pair of brackets (or commas or dashes).

I've just used four parentheses to enclose two parentheses – but I wouldn't usually mix senses like this as it gets too confusing.

Actually, since one bracket is rarely found without its 'other half', the singular form *parenthesis* more often refers to the inserted material, but this is not mandatory. To really disambiguate, the term 'parenthetical', used as a noun, is often used for the 'inserted material' sense.

**2** **Parentheses** is usually used to refer the pair of brackets often used to set off a parenthetical – but the term could also be used for more than one parenthetical.

See http://josecarillo.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/parenthesis-isnt-just-optional-material.html for further thoughts on the matter.

Comment: At first glance, this would seem confusing, but it actually does throw a lot of light on the matter. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’ describes *parenthesis* as ‘a string of words interpolated into a sentence but syntactically independent of it’.

It describes *parentheses* as:

> . . . the standard name for round brackets in the US and Canada, and
>   increasingly in Australia. In the UK **parentheses** is still mostly a
>   technical term, by BNC evidence, where it appears in scientific and
>   bureaucratic documents. But overall British writers are about three
>   times more likely to use **in brackets** than **in parentheses**.

This means that if I write a sentence (I don’t mean with a pen) the words ‘I don’t mean with a pen’ are a parenthesis, and the marks at the beginning and end of them are parentheses.