# Parenthesis and parentheses

Tags: grammatical-number, punctuation

What does a parenthesis mean, "(" or ")" or "(...)" ?

In (abc), do I say that abc is inside the parentheses, or inside the parenthesis?

Comment: "Parentheses" is the plural of "parenthesis".  "(" is a parenthesis, "()" is parentheses.

Comment: You would say that *abc is inside* ***parentheses*** or *inside **a pair of** parentheses*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["parentheses" vs "parenthesis"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130219/parentheses-vs-parenthesis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people confuse **Paranthesis** to be "(" or ")" or "(...)". When in actual the parenthesis is any amplifying or explanatory word, phrase, or sentence that’s set off from a sentence or passage by some form of punctuation.

It can be a pair of enclosing commas, a pair of enclosing dashes or parentheses.

Here are few examples:

1. **Parenthesis by comma:**  “Ferdinand Magellan, who claimed the Philippine islands for the Spanish crown in 1521, was actually a Portuguese whose native name was Fernão Magalhães.”
2. **Parenthesis by dashes:** “Their kindly uncle was terminally ill—they said they didn’t know it then—but his nephews and nieces just went on their merry ways.”
3. **Parenthesis by parentheses:** “While I was driving it out of the used-car dealer’s yard, the nicely refurbished 1994 sedan (the dealer assured me its engine had just been overhauled) busted one of its pistons.”

Read [this blog](http://josecarillo.blogspot.com/2009/12/parenthesis-isnt-just-optional-material.html) for further details.

**Parentheses** means a pair of "(" and ")". Hence in your example, one would say "abc is inside the parentheses".

In modern days, people use **paranthesis** as any one of "(" or ")" which is widely accepted.

Comment: Oh my goodness. Now I have to apologize to the many people who have endured me totally misusing these words. I thought that the former was the singular of the latter.